# Quick Way to compute eigenvalues/eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

My professor uploaded this response to a practice question.

The beginning makes sense because the dimension of the kernel is geometric multiplicity of the vectors (which I can compute myself)

But then he suddenly (out of nowhere) finds out that the next eigenvalue is 2? Is there a simple calculation I'm missing?

The last part makes sense, since all the eigenvalues add up to the trace of the matrix (0).

Any help would be great!

Comment: He just sees that $(1,1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector. Indeed, multiplying any row with this vector just gives $2$. He understands the matrix product well, and that gives him the ability to see this one.

Answer (score 0):

Experience, simple as that. The vector $(1,1,1,1)$ is often one to try as an eigenvector, as it just forms the row sums.
Here, we see that every row consists of two ones and two zeros, hence the sum of each row is two and we have found our eigenvalue $2$.

If you want to see how $(1,1,1,1)$ forms row sums, take some other matrices and multiply them with this vector.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of the rows of a matrix are all the same, then the vector consisting of all $1$s will be an eigenvector, and the associated eigenvalue will be the sum. Its not hard to prove, and its the result I applied to get the third eigenvalue.

Seeing the fourth is sort of a "process of elimination" thing.